# Creating the delineate_crown function using lidR package in R?

Tags: r, lidr

I can't seem to create a `delineate_crown()` function using the `lidR` package. I am using the example code given at page 33 of lidR.pdf to get familiar with the function. Furthermore, I tried playing with both `tree_hulls()` and `delineate_crown()`, and I don't know what I am doing wrong. When I try to plot (line 15) using the delineate_crown function, I get the this error:

```
Error in curve(expr = x, from = from, to = to, xlim = xlim, ylab = ylab,  : 
  'expr' did not evaluate to an object of length 'n'
```

I have tried to make the example code simple. I am actually using the code on the `tree_hulls()` source code page (https://rdrr.io/cran/lidR/src/R/tree_hulls.r). As I am not that experienced with R, I can't seem to create the object convex_hulls at line 9 and so I can't plot it. The code is as follows:

```
#Compute convex hull
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las <- readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz0", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")
# NOTE: This dataset is already segmented
plot(las, colorPalette = pastel.colors(200))
# Only the hulls
tree_hulls = function(las, type = c("convex", "concave", "bbox"), concavity = 3,length_threshold = 0, func = NULL, attribute = "treeID") 
convex_hulls = tree_hulls(las)
plot(convex_hulls)
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. Use a dataset shipped with the package instead of your own dataset. Your code is not a valid code. I have 8 errors that are not related to `lidR` but to meaningless R code. Why are you defining a generic function L7-10? This definition is incorrect (`LAS` vs `las`). Why are you defining a function without body L13? Why are you trying trying to redefine functions from the package? What L36 means? It is not a valid R code. Your example looks like a confusing mix of partial copy of the source code of the package mixed with partial copy of the documentation.

Comment: I've added the R tag because that might help the right people find this.

Comment: As a student, I am still learning things

Comment: You put the page number of the documentation in your example and you did not even tried your own example before to post. Being a student cannot explain that. Please make a reproducible example and please explain what you are trying to do so we can help you.

Comment: I have edited the question to avoid any further confusion. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm still unable to understand what you are trying to do. Your example is the one from the documentation but with some modifications that are not valid R syntax and you are not explaining why you changed something and what are your intentions behind these modifications. The original example from the documentation works well and your example does not throw the error you are mentioning.

```r
library(lidR)
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "MixedConifer.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile, select = "xyz0", filter = "-drop_z_below 0")

convex_hulls = delineate_crowns(las)
plot(convex_hulls)
```

[image]

Please note that `tree_hull()` is deprecated from [version 3.0.0](https://github.com/Jean-Romain/lidR/releases/tag/v3.0.0). It is replaced by `delineate_crown()` that does the same.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me to the up to date version, I was using version 2.2.4. Yes, I just wanted to plot 2D convex hull just like in your answer. And the code does work,but in case of my test las file, I am getting this error > Error in eval(bysub, x, parent.frame()) : object 'treeID' not found. How can I fix this please?

Comment: You must segment the tree first with `segment_trees()` (or `lastrees()` before v3)